# RadEditor UploadPaths Absolute File Paths

Tags: c#, .net, path, rad

I am trying to set the `uploadpaths` for all of the RadEditor File Managers to the same absolute file path, and *also* share the same path across a couple of Solutions on the same machine.

So, I wrote a method to get the path from the Web.Config and set all the Properties on the `FileManagerDialogConfiguration` objects (`UploadPaths`, `ViewPaths`, etc). The problem is these properties are looking for Virtual Paths, and full paths don't work.

How can I supply the properties with the Virtual Path of a folder that may/may not be in the same Solution?

This didn't work:

```
private static FileManagerDialogConfiguration fixPaths(FileManagerDialogConfiguration f, String[] path)
{
    if (path[0][0] != '~')
    {
        Uri basePath = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["veMainPath"]);
        Uri absPath = new Uri(path[0]);
        Uri relPath = basePath.MakeRelativeUri(absPath);
        path[0] = relPath.LocalPath;
    }

    f.ViewPaths = path;
    f.UploadPaths = path;
    f.DeletePaths = path;
    f.MaxUploadFileSize = 10485760;
    return f;
}
```